# Insert from array<> java into table sql where not exists

Tags: java, sql

i want insert data from array this array it's contains variable of class java getters and setters 
So i can insert that but when i execute another timen it will be added for second time so i have repitition
for that i want do insert if where not exist to not have repitito of same data

this the code but its the same tha sam data are inserted for next time

```
for(Service srv:service){
    srvDataLst.add(srv.getvlan());

PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO tout (VLAN,client,JR,vrf,address) "
    + "SELECT DISTINCT '"+srv.getvlan()+"', ?, ?, ?, ? "  
    + "   FROM dual "
    + "   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tout WHERE 'VLAN'='"+srv.getvlan()+"')"
    + " ");
        pst.setString(1,convertNullToEmptyString(srv.getdesc()));
    pst.setString(2,convertNullToEmptyString(srv.getjr()));
    pst.setString(3,convertNullToEmptyString(srv.getvrf()));
    pst.setString(4,convertNullToEmptyString(srv.getaddress()));
    pst.executeUpdate();
```

Thank you

Comment: Why no unique constraint/index on VLAN? And a simple INSERT VALUES.

Comment: because when i execut second time it will inserted same data

Comment: Mr Admin it's not resolved .. so im trying to do a new question to help me thank you